# java -version still shows old $JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I unknowingly downloaded the wrong jdk onto my system (openjdk 11) and would prefer java 1.8.0_181 to be installed. I'm just looking to run an application so I believe that jre is all that is needed. I got the official release from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre8-downloads-2133155.html for linux x64.

I now have both of these java version on my ubuntu machine. the jdk is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/` and I placed the jre folder in `/usr/lib/java/`. I have set the `$JAVA_HOME` path to `/usr/lib/java/jre1.8.0_181` in both `/etc/environment` and in `./bashrc`.

When I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` the correct path shows up (jre path). However, when I do java -version, it still shows as java Version 10 instead of 1.8.0_181.

Can anyone assist with this? I'm not sure what else I can do here.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to set add the lines `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jre1.8.0_181"` and `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` to my ~./profile file. Then turn off my machine and get back on.